# Using multiple positive images to train Haar Cascades

Tags: python, opencv, haar-classifier

HI Im new to Haar Cascades. Im following this tutorial to create a Haar.

now my problem is. In this tutorial he uses only one positive image. I need to use multiple positive images. How can I do that any suggestions.

This is where he starts training the cascade

```
opencv_createsamples -img watch5050.jpg -bg bg.txt -info info/info.lst -pngoutput info -maxxangle 0.5 -maxyangle 0.5 -maxzangle 0.5 -num 1950
```

Here he uses only watch5050.jpg
Is there a way to modify this to use multiple positive images?

Comment: do you want to create additional positive samples with geometric transformations from your multiple posizove images, or do you want to use your positive samples as they are? Afaik there is a tool zo combine multiple .vec files, but I never used it...

Comment: Yup I need that

Comment: have a look at: https://github.com/wulfebw/mergevec which looks like a tool to merge different .vec files, so you can use your _createsamples command for each input image and merge the .vec files afterwards. Hoewever using the transformed images might or might not be a good idea at all, it depends on your kind of input data.

Comment: OK thanks a lot will do that